# Accessing a partial view from a different control from within an area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas

Within an MVC view I'd like to access a partial view from a different controller. Before I explain my issue at hand you should know where everything is in my solution:

```
Areas      
   MyArea    
        Views
         Cont1
           PartialPages
           ViewImIn
         Cont2
            PartialPages
               ViewICall
```

Now, in ViewImIn.cshtml I call ViewIcall.cshtml like this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Cont2/PartialPages/ViewICall.cshtml", Model)
```

But I keep getting the error stating that the "partial view was not found or view engine does not support searched locatio..."

I've also tried "../Cont2/PartialPages/ViewICall" and variations of it.

Comment: You won't run into these kind of issues if you use [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling it like this

```
 @{Html.RenderPartial("ViewICall");}
```

Comment: This did not work, it only searched the Cont1 directory (and its sub directories) and the shared folder of the project with different areas (i.e. the main project).. It did not check Cont2 or its sub directories

Comment: I see, I mis-read your question.  You should put shared views in a shared folder so MVC knows where to find it.  It's difficult to tell mvc to look where it wouldn't normally.  Your best bet is to move the view into a shared folder.

Comment: O wait It did not work.. I was using the sub project.. it doesnt work when i try this within an area... & it should be @{Html.RenderPartial("ViewICall", Model);}

Comment: If your view lives in Areas/MyArea/Views/Shared it will be accessible to the area.  Alternatively, if it lives in MyProject/Views/Shared it is accessible to everyone.  (and passing the model is redundant, but harmless, if your partial view is strongly typed:))

Comment: Our engine is custom.. I think that's why it does not work.. I will put it in the Shared of the overall project (the one with Areas)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a PartialPages folder under Cont2, you should have a Shared folder directly under Views.  Then it should be able to found directly with:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("ViewICall", Model);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use RenderAction which may or may not be what your looking for. If the Model is different for the ViewICall or you'd like to separate the Model/logic; then you can use RenderAction which will allow you call a Controller method and render the result. If the partial view you're trying to render uses the same Model as your current view, then use RenderPartial.

- [Here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) is a post by Phil Haack on Html.RenderAction and Html.Action
- [Here](http://captaincodeman.com/2009/02/21/when-to-use-renderaction-vs-renderpartial-with-asp-net-mvc/) is a post on when to use RenderAction and when to use RenderPartial